# Turtle Crashing In While Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

When I initialise Turtle in the script below, it always hangs.
I am using Python IDLE 3.9.0a3. I have tried adding IDLE config to turtle.cfg, to no avail.
The code that I am using is:

```
from turtle import *
speed(0)

while True:
    penup()
    home()
    setheading(0)
    num = int(input('Number to check?'))
    ang = int(input('Angle to turn?'))
    pendown()
    print(num)
    while True:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = num // 2
            print(num)
            right(ang)
        if num == 1:
            break
        if num % 2 != 0:
            num = num * 3
            num = num + 1
            print(num)
            left(ang)
```

Comment: You have two while loops. The first one can be interrupted by the ```break``` statement, but the other one (the outer one) has no way to stop.

Comment: @flyinthelotion I was able to add a `break` command to the outer loop, but Turtle still hangs. It triggers if the starting number equals the number that the program is set to end at.

Comment: If I run your code without the first while loop (i.e. I do one run), it runs fine on my machine. What is the problem exactly, and what is the desired output of your program?

Comment: It is meant to create a Collatz Conjecture Coral (see here: [link](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wH141HLD57o/maxresdefault.jpg)). Obviously I haven't added the colour change/pen thickness, but the whole idea is that it overlaps and creates interesting patterns, not just creating a single line. It kind of needs to be in a loop for this to happen.

Comment: please accept the answer if it helped you out, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the whole idea is that it overlaps and creates interesting patterns,
> not just creating a single line. It kind of needs to be in a loop for
> this to happen ... I tried this, and Turtle still hangs...

Let's try a different approach.  First we'll toss the problematic `while True:` statements.  Next, we'll treat the user input as a limit, so we'll do all the lines up to that number.  Instead of a non-blocking tight loop, which might cause the OS problems, we'll use a timer event to start each arm and allow events to run in between:

```
from turtle import *

limit = int(input('Limit of check?'))
angle = int(input('Angle to turn?'))

hideturtle()
tracer(False)

candidate = 1

def draw():
    global candidate

    if candidate < limit:

        number = candidate
        pendown()

        while number != 1:

            if number % 2 == 0:
                number //= 2
                right(angle)
                forward(10)
            else:
                number = number * 3 + 1
                left(angle)
                forward(10)

        update()
        penup()
        home()

        candidate += 1
        ontimer(draw, 25)  # milliseconds

draw()

exitonclick()
```

See if this runs any better for you.  The next enhancement might be to use turtle's `numinput(...)` instead of `int(input(...))`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There were some things that I changed in your code, but it appears to be working on my machine

1. I added `forward()` which makes sure that the pen actually travels further instead of only turning. The 10 is a distance metric, you can play around with it.
2. I added the `exitonclick()` function, which makes sure that the turtle screen closes when you click on it

Note that the outer while loop is removed here for testing purposes, but you can add it back easily enough.

```py
from turtle import *
speed(0)

penup()
home()
setheading(0)
num = int(input('Number to check?'))
ang = int(input('Angle to turn?'))
pendown()
print(num)
while True:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        num = num // 2
        print(num)
        right(ang)
        forward(10)
    elif num == 1:
        break
    else:
        num = num * 3
        num = num + 1
        print(num)
        left(ang)
        forward(10)
exitonclick()
```

Comment: I tried this, and Turtle still hangs... thank you for your help either way, it is probably a problem with something else other than the code. Still, your reformatting is way better!